# clang python bindings: how to find type of a variable

Tags: python, c++, clang

I'm experimenting with clang and its python bindings for processing the AST of C/C++ code.

I have the following test C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class myclass {
public:
        void mymethod() {
                printf("method\n");
        }
};

void testfunc() {
        myclass var;
        var.mymethod();
}
```

and I wrote the following python code (simplified & shortened) to walk through it:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import clang.cindex
import sys

def walk(node):
    if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.CALL_EXPR:
        print 'name: %s, type: %s' % (node.spelling or node.displayname, node.type.spelling)

    for c in node.get_children():
        walk(c)

index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
walk(index.parse(sys.argv[1]).cursor)
```

Now when my code reaches var.mymethod() in testfunc, it shows "mymethod" and "void". Not what I expected. I'm trying to retrieve the class type of on which mymethod is called, not the return-type of the method.

Comment: You ARE requesting the "type" for the call-expr (so the return type from the call to `mymethod`). Not surprising at all that it is `void mymethod()` - I bet if you change it to `int` it will indeed show you it as `int`.

Comment: Indeed, you're right! That explains it. Can you also tell me how to get the class-type on which I'm invoking the method? That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Probably can give you a hint, but I'm not an expert in walking AST's. My "expertise" if I have any is with generating code for LLVM. I'll have to dig into it a bit first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment above, you are getting the return-type of the function. This is not the type of the variable from which `mymethod` is called.

Looking at the AST output (using clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fno-diagnostics-color), this is the definition of `testfunc`

```
`-FunctionDecl 0x5e14080 <line:9:1, line:12:1> line:9:6 testfunc 'void ()'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x5e14750 <col:17, line:12:1>
    |-DeclStmt 0x5e146b0 <line:10:9, col:20>
    | `-VarDecl 0x5e14130 <col:9, col:17> col:17 used var 'myclass' callinit
    |   `-CXXConstructExpr 0x5e14680 <col:17> 'myclass' 'void () noexcept'
    `-CXXMemberCallExpr 0x5e14728 <line:11:9, col:22> 'void'
      `-MemberExpr 0x5e146f0 <col:9, col:13> '<bound member function type>' .mymethod 0x5e13dd0
        `-DeclRefExpr 0x5e146c8 <col:9> 'myclass' lvalue Var 0x5e14130 'var' 'myclass'
```

You can then see that INSIDE the `CXXMemberCallExpr`, you have a `MemberExpr` and inside that a `DeclRefExpr` that refers back to `var` and its type `myclass`. Exactly how you write that in Python, I'm not sure, but it shouldn't be terribly hard to figure out by dumping some of the inner structures from your CALL_EXPR entry.

Using the code above, I modified it to look like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import clang.cindex
import sys

def find_decl_ref_expr(node):
    for c in node.get_children():
        if c.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.DECL_REF_EXPR:
            print "Member function call via", c.type.spelling, c.displayname
        else:
            find_decl_ref_expr(c)


def called_from(node):
    for c in node.get_children():
        if c.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.MEMBER_REF_EXPR:
            find_decl_ref_expr(c);

def walk(node):
    if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.CALL_EXPR:
        print 'name: %s, type: %s' % (node.spelling or node.displayname, node.type.spelling)
    called_from(node)

    for c in node.get_children():
        walk(c)

index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
walk(index.parse(sys.argv[1]).cursor)
```

It kind of works, but it's definitely not a complete solution. For example adding a pointer that is used via an array also prints the index used to get into the array. For complete understanding of complex code, I'm not sure what you actually need to do [e.g. if `myclass` is several layers into a class with various pointer and index operations].

I'm also posting some code I was using this to inspect what's in each node:

```
def dump_children(node):
    for c in node.get_children():
        print c.kind, c.type.spelling
        dump_children(c)
```

Comment: It is hard, it looks very different from how the C++ api does things (have been looking at for a while now). So if anyone wants to step in...?

Comment: I just dumped the stuff from inside your sample-code, doesn't look too different, I shall see if I can make something work.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!